# Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, ormlite

Estou fazendo a seguinte query no android usando o OrmLite:

```
List<Mensagem> msgs = SqliteOrm.getMensagemDao(this).queryForAll();
```

porém estou recebendo o erro abaixo:

```
Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 0):

o erro diz certifique-se de que a sua classe cursor está corretamente inicializada antes de acessar os dados...

provavelmente voce está tentando inicializar a linha/coluna direto do cursor, só que o cursor nao tem linha/coluna. recomendo olhar o valor de retorno do seu cursor e verificar se o valor de retorno está retornando para um valor possivel

como pode ser outra coisa seria bom por ou o logCat ou o restante do codigo para ajudar, pois as vezes pode ocorrer o mesmo erro por excesso de dados, ou a falta deles